# WIll .env File Variables be exposed to Users in Nextjs?

Tags: web-applications, next.js, dotenv

I am building a webapp using `nextjs`. I added some dependencies like `Mux` and `Firestore`. In order to store api_keys and others in an organized way, I created `.env` file and put it in the root directory.

I checked the rules for `.env` in `nextjs`. Here is the reference: https://medium.com/courtly-intrepid/environmental-variables-in-next-js-with-dotenv-599c5bbfdf74. I added `NEXT_PUBLIC` prefix for variables, then they were resolved successfully.

However, after checking the `nextjs` official docs https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables, it says the variables will be exposed to **browser**.
I feel confused about **browser**. Does it mean if a user use his/her browser to use my app, my enviroment varibles will also be exposed to him/her?

One thing I was thinking, if I put all codes that need dotenv into backend side, Can I make these variables not to users? For current version, I used dotenv in the components which, I think, might cause varibles seen by frontend users?
[Screenshot of code in Component which needs dotenv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTGim.png)

P.S.: I am new here. I don't have enough reputation to show your screenshot directly. The link is used instead.

Comment: _"if a user use his/her browser to use my app, my enviroment varibles will also be exposed to him/her"_ - Yes, that's exactly what it means. Any environment variable that uses the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix will be exposed and visible on the browser.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you to use `NEXT_PUBLIC` prefix, but if you want that your variables mantain 100% isolated from frontend, you could do this:

Create and `.env` file:

```
TOKEN = 45354354353
```

`next.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    TOKEN: process.env.TOKEN,
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks, does it mean `NEXT_PUBLIC` prefix will make variables available for users?

Comment: It will be exposed to the frontend, but is not so easy to obtain them.

Comment: Thanks you! If i was usefull to you, please rate my answer!

Comment: Sure! Is just to click the ^ arrow ? I tried this but my reputation is too low.

Comment: Don't worry man! Good luck in your project